# tidyverse: Cross tables of one variable with all other variables in data.frame

Tags: r, tidyverse, crosstab, purrr, janitor

I want to make cross table of a variable with all other variables in the data.frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

humans <- starwars %>%
  filter(species == "Human")

humans %>%
  janitor::tabyl(gender, eye_color)



gender blue blue-gray brown dark hazel yellow
 female    3         0     5    0     1      0
   male    9         1    12    1     1      2

humans %>%
  dplyr::select_if(is.character) %>%
  dplyr::select(-name, -gender) %>%
  purrr::map(.f = ~janitor::tabyl(dat = humans, gender, .x))

Error: Unknown columns `blond`, `none`, `brown`, `brown, grey`, `brown` and ... 
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tably` takes names as arguments and you passed a vector to it.

If you use `imap` you'll have access to the name of the column, that you can convert to a symbol, and as `janitor` supports quasi-quotation you can write:

```
humans %>%
  select_if(is.character) %>%
  select(-name, -gender) %>%
  imap(.f = ~janitor::tabyl(dat = humans, !!sym(.y), gender))
#$`hair_color`
#     hair_color female male
#         auburn      1    0
#   auburn, grey      0    1
#  auburn, white      0    1
#          black      1    7
#          blond      0    3
#          brown      6    8
#    brown, grey      0    1
#           grey      0    1
#           none      0    3
#          white      1    1
# 
# $skin_color
#  skin_color female male
#        dark      0    4
#        fair      3   13
```

Interestingly `tabyl.data.frame` calls an unexported function that works on symbols so by calling it directly we can skip the unquoting and use base R.

```
cols <- setdiff(names(Filter(is.character,humans)), c("name","gender"))
lapply(cols, function(x) janitor:::tabyl_2way(humans, as.name(x), quote(gender)))
# [[1]]
#     hair_color female male
#         auburn      1    0
#   auburn, grey      0    1
#  auburn, white      0    1
#          black      1    7
#          blond      0    3
#          brown      6    8
#    brown, grey      0    1
#           grey      0    1
#           none      0    3
#          white      1    1
# 
# [[2]]
#  skin_color female male
#        dark      0    4
```

To make it work with `xtable` @akrun's suggestion works here as well :

```
humans %>%
  select_if(is.character) %>%
  select(-name, -gender) %>%
  imap(.f = ~tabyl(dat = humans, !!sym(.y), gender) %>% rename_at(1,~"x")) %>%
  xtableList
```

or

```
cols <- setdiff(names(Filter(is.character,humans)), c("name","gender"))
l <- lapply(cols, function(x) {
  res <- janitor:::tabyl_2way(humans, as.name(x), quote(gender))
  names(res)[1] <- "x"
  res
})
xtableList(l)
```

Comment: Thanks @Moody_Mudskipper for your answer. However, still not able to render the output to .Rnw using xtable as 
humans %>%
  select_if(is.character) %>%
  select(-name, -gender) %>%
  imap(.f = ~janitor::tabyl(dat = humans, !!sym(.y), gender))  %>%
             xtableList

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that we need pairwise table with 'gender'

```
humans %>%
  dplyr::select_if(is.character) %>%
  dplyr::select(-name, -gender) %>%
  imap(~ tibble(!! .y := .x) %>% 
             mutate(gender = humans[['gender']]) %>% 
             janitor::tabyl(!!rlang::sym(names(.)[1]), gender))
#$hair_color
#    hair_color female male
#        auburn      1    0
#  auburn, grey      0    1
# auburn, white      0    1
#         black      1    7
#         blond      0    3
#        brown      6    8
#  brown, grey      0    1
#         grey      0    1
#         none      0    3
#        white      1    1

#$skin_color
# skin_color female male
#       dark      0    4
#       fair      3   13
#      light      6    5
#...
```

#### Update

The `xtable::xtableList` requires names to be same across the `list` elements.  To make that happen, change the first column name same across the `list` elements and then create an identifier column

```
library(xtable)
humans %>%
 dplyr::select_if(is.character) %>%
 dplyr::select(-name, -gender) %>%
 imap(~ tibble(!! .y := .x) %>% 
         mutate(gender = humans[['gender']]) %>% 
         janitor::tabyl(!!rlang::sym(names(.)[1]), gender) %>%  
         mutate(colNname = .y) %>% 
         rename_at(1, ~ 'Variable')) %>%
 xtableList
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for very useful answer. However, not able to render the output in `.Rnw` using `xtable::xtableList`. Any thoughts.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I think the issue with the names that are not common.  You can make the names common and create a new column as identifier, i.e. `humans %>%
  dplyr::select_if(is.character) %>%
  dplyr::select(-name, -gender) %>%
  imap(~ tibble(!! .y := .x) %>% 
             mutate(gender = humans[['gender']]) %>% 
             janitor::tabyl(!!rlang::sym(names(.)[1]), gender) %>% mutate(colNname = .y) %>% rename_at(1, ~ 'Variable')) %>% xtableList`

Answer (score 0):

Using only `data.table` (and one `%>%`):

```
library(data.table)
swDT <- data.table(starwars)
setkey(swDT, gender, hair_color)


swDT[species == "Human"
     ][CJ(gender, hair_color, unique =TRUE), .N, .EACHI] %>% 
  dcast(hair_color ~ gender, value.var = "N")


       hair_color female male
 1:        auburn      1    0
 2:  auburn, grey      0    1
 3: auburn, white      0    1
 4:         black      1    7
 5:         blond      0    3
 6:         brown      6    8
 7:   brown, grey      0    1
 8:          grey      0    1
 9:          none      0    3
10:         white      1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

The list-columns in `starwars` add complexity, but here's an example with `mtcars`: crosstab `cyl` against all other variables.

```
mtcars %>%
  tidyr::gather(var, value, -cyl) %>%
  janitor::tabyl(cyl, value, var, show_missing_levels = FALSE) %>%
  purrr::map2(.x = ., .y = names(.), ~ janitor::adorn_title(.x, col_name = .y))
```

Returns a list of crosstabs.  cyl *x* am, cyl *x* carb, etc. :

```
$`am`
     am  
 cyl  0 1
   4  3 8
   6  4 3
   8 12 2

$carb
     carb          
 cyl    1 2 3 4 6 8
   4    5 6 0 0 0 0
   6    2 0 0 4 1 0
   8    0 4 3 6 0 1

...
```

If you will do further manipulation of these data.frames you may find this title option friendlier:

```
purrr::map2(.x = ., .y = names(.), ~ janitor::adorn_title(.x, col_name = .y, placement = "combined"))
```

Which gives you:

```
$vs
 cyl/vs  0  1
      4  1 10
      6  3  4
      8 14  0
```