# How to count frequencies by columns for each group

Tags: r

I have a dataset called `ballons` with two clusters : True and false.
I'm searching to count modalities frequencies per cluster and per column, so I tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

ballons=structure(list(YELLOW = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("PURPLE", 
"YELLOW"), class = "factor"), SMALL = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("LARGE", "SMALL"), class = "factor"), STRETCH = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("DIP", "STRETCH"), class = "factor"), ADULT = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("ADULT", "CHILD"), class = "factor"), T = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))

r1=group_split(ballons %>%
  group_by(T))

print(r1)


data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(r1,function(x) sapply(x,table))))


  YELLOW SMALL STRETCH ADULT  T
1   6, 6  6, 6    8, 4  4, 8 12
2   4, 3  4, 3    0, 7  7, 0  7
```

However I'm searching this representation ( **expected output** ):

```
      YELLOW PURPLE SMALL LARGE ...
FALSE   6    6      6      6    ...
TRUE    4    3      4      3    etc
```

I also tried without success:

```
lapply(r1,function(x) sapply(x,table))
data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(r1,function(x) sapply(x,table))))
sapply(ballons,table,ballons$T)
```

Comment: Not specific to this question, but calling a column `T` might cause some headaches at some point, either by confusing functions or confusing yourself, since it can be used as a shorthand to evaluate to `TRUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using tidyverse so you can use a tidy solution

```
table(ballons %>% pivot_longer(cols = !c(T)) %>% select(T,value))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be to use `janitor::tabyl` which is useful for tables:

```
library(janitor)
tabyl(ballons, T, YELLOW)
#      T PURPLE YELLOW
#  FALSE      6      6
#   TRUE      4      3
```

Now loop over all columns and then join output:

```
ballons[-5] %>% 
  imap(~tabyl(dat = ballons, T, !!sym(.y))) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "T")
#      T PURPLE YELLOW LARGE SMALL DIP STRETCH ADULT CHILD
#  FALSE      6      6     6     6   8       4     4     8
#   TRUE      4      3     4     3   0       7     7     0
```

`!!sym` helps convert the individual columns to objects, see @Lionel Henry explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57704339/4083743) and @Moody_Mudskipper with `tabyl` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54796143/4083743).

Comment: Could you explain what `!!sym` is doing here?

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

ballons %>% 
  pivot_longer(-T) %>% 
  pivot_wider(T, names_from = value, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 9
#>   T     YELLOW SMALL STRETCH ADULT CHILD   DIP LARGE PURPLE
#>   <lgl>  <int> <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#> 1 TRUE       3     3       7     7     0     0     4      4
#> 2 FALSE      6     6       4     4     8     8     6      6
```